# Why isn't my char array printing out in C?

Tags: c, pointers, char

I have this program that is trying to convert a character string to a different base without using atoi.  Why isn't the output printing at the end? The text "Output:" prints, but there is nothing after it.

The code seems to work up until that point.  I went ahead and added the null byte.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Int(char* numstring, int base) {

    char *digitPtr = numstring;
    char ans[100];

    int decVal = 0;
    int totalVal = 0;

    int numDigits = 0;

    // Go through the entire string to get the decimal value of the number.

    while (*digitPtr != '\0') {
        numDigits++;
        digitPtr++;
    }

    // Now calculate decimal value of the string.

    printf("before decimal value calc \n");
    //  *digitPtr = numstring;

    int length = numDigits;

    numDigits--;

    printf("numDigits: %d \n", numDigits);

    
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("calcuating the dec \n");
        decVal = (*numstring - 48);
        printf("dec Value: %d \n", decVal);
        printf("power: %f \n", pow(10, numDigits));     

        totalVal = totalVal + decVal *  pow(10, numDigits);

        printf("totalVal %d \n", totalVal);
        numDigits--;
        numstring++; 
    }

    //*digitPtr = numstring;
    numDigits = length;

    printf("totalVal %d \n", totalVal);

    while (totalVal > 0) {
        int remainder = totalVal % base;
        printf("remainder: %d \n", remainder);
        totalVal = totalVal / base;
        ans[numDigits] = remainder;
        numDigits--;
    }

    ans[99] = '\0'; 

    printf("Output: %s \n", ans); 
}

int main() {
```

Comment: `ans[numDigits] = remainder + '0'`

Comment: Also, using `numDigits` as the index does not look right. For example, if there is one digit then that will store into `ans[1]` instead of `ans[0]`. `ans[99] = '\0';` is wrong too as it puts the NUL at the end of the array instead of at the end of the digit sequence - result is that there is garbage after the digits which `printf` will try to parse as part of the string.

Comment: Anyway unless you are making the function as an homework, you could use `strtol`

Comment: I received a notification of you saying that it's not an homework. (But  then you deleted the comment) In this case you really don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yeah, it’s not a homework but it’s a “challenge” where you aren’t supposed to use those functions

Comment: As a general note:`(*numstring - 48);` Don't use magic numbers. If you mean `'0'` write `'0'` not some numerical value that depends on character encoding and most people must look up in an ASCII chart first.

Comment: @Groo Okay, this prints something out....but why?

Comment: @BobBobsonTheThirdEsq.: I haven't analyzed the code too much, but the same way like you subtracted 48 (ascii code for '0') from the ascii character when converting into a numerical value, you will have to add 48 when converting back. But there are several other errors with the code, and I would recommend splitting this code into two separate functions, and then testing them individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't print anything because you're assigning the numerical value of the remainder to a `char`, but you're not considering that numbers start at 48 (that is, `'0'`) in the ASCII table, so you should add the "starting point" to your remainder:

```
ans[numDigits] = remainder + '0';
```

That said, there's another problem: you're assigning the length of the input value to `numDigits` before the `while` loop, but the length of the number won't probably be the same as length of the number in the new base (for example, 32 in base 10 is two digits long, but in base 2 it has four more digits). A solution could be to make `numDigits` start at 0, increment it after every iteration and print the string character by character in reverse order. Alternatively a mathematical approach for taking the number of digits of a number in a custom base is adding one to the rounded-down logarithm of the number in the custom base. To do so you can you the properties of logarithm since C standard libraries only provide logs in base 2, e, and 10.

```
numDigits = (int)(floor(log(totalVal) / log(base) + 1);
```

Following this approach you don't have to change your loop and you can print the result as a string.

Note that you shouldn't set `ans[99]` to `'\0';` since there could be garbage between the converted number and the end of the string; instead, you should set it to `numDigits`. You could also initialize `ans` to `0` (which is the numerical representation of `\0`), so you can forget about manually setting the terminator.